# child_process Spawn errors ENOENT (like exec)

Tags: child-process

I know there are many people with this same problem but ive tried them all and havent been able to achieve the following.

#### I have the following function

```
let { exec, spawn } = require('child_process');
export const buildServer = async (silent?) => {
    try {
        const child = spawn('ng run boilerplate:server:production;', []);

        child.on('exit', (code) => {
            console.log(`Child process exited with code ${code}`);
        });

        child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
            console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
        });

        child.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
            console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
        });

    } catch (error) { throw error; }
}
```

#### This is the basic implementation of `spawn`. Here is the error I get

> Error: spawn ng run boilerplate:server:production; ENOENT

### How can i run that command (`ng ...`) without buffering the output?

are there any alternatives you know of?

Answer (score 0):

I finally bumped in to this article https://medium.com/edge-coders/node-js-child-processes-everything-you-need-to-know-e69498fe970a

now my function works like this.

```
export const stream = async (cmd: string, silent?) => {
    if (!silent) { console.log("[running] ".gray, `${cmd}`.green.bold); }
    try {
        const child = spawn(cmd, {
            stdio: 'inherit',
            shell: true
        });

    } catch (error) { throw error; }
}
```